# Create texture without TexImage2D

Tags: node.js, opengl

Is this possible to create an OpenGL texture without sending an array of pixel data to the driver, and using glVertex or similar?

Node-x11 GLX implementation lacks TexImage2D function, so I am trying to find the way aroundto create a texture.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You cannot implement texture mapping with vertices. Even if you created a bunch of point primitives and colored them it would be ridiculously slow and you still would not be able to implement texture filtering, perspective correction, proper scaling, etc.

Comment: afaik you can create gl texture from (previously uploaded with PutImage) X pixmap - but I don't have concrete example and likely there are some requests still missing if you go that path (but easy to add)